# mapping local folder as a network drive in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, networking

Can someone please tell me how to map a local folder as a network folder.I have to do some testing locally and was wondering if this is possible..What I have is a folder on C drive C:\InetPub\Contents and I would like to access it as \\servername\contents .

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just share the folder and then map as \COMPUTERNAME\Contents